# Python file i/o looping, why doesn't dictionary get updated?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, io

I am trying to create a function that opens a file for reading, skips the first line because it is the header, gets every line and splits at ':' to get keys and values to put into a dictionary and then return that dictionary. My problem is that my function is just giving me an empty dictionary. How do I fix this?

> ex from line 2: 'Bulbasaur': (1, 'Grass', 'Poison', 1, False)

'Bulbasaur' is the key and everything after colon is the value for that key.

> So I need to return: my_dict={'bulbasaur':(1, 'Grass', 'Poison', 1, False)}

Here is my function:

```
def read_info_file(filename):
    f=open(filename, 'r') #open file for reading
    lines=f.readlines()[1:] #skip first line
    d={} #create dictionary
    for lines in f: #iterate for all lines
        x=lines.split(':') #split at colon
        a=x[0] #map keys to values
        b=x[1]
        d[a]=b #add to dictionary
    return d #return dictionary
```

Comment: Sounds like your file is empty. Make sure you open the **correct** file.

Comment: The file shouldn't be empty as it is in a tester that has multiple files

Comment: Yet if the file contains 0 or 1 line, then the `for` loop never gets executed and you end up with an empty dictionary. All other codepaths produce either an error, or a dictionary with values.

Comment: If the function worked, I would be passing some test cases as not all files are empty. If it worked, I would only fail testcases that have empty files.

Comment: `readlines` has exhausted the file, there's nothing left for the `for` loop.  `for line in lines` is probably what you meant.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: bingo, I missed that, and that's the one thing that stanleyli fixed below but failed to mention.

Answer (score 2):

`f = open(filename, 'r')` gives your an iterator over the lines of the file.

After you do `lines = f.readlines()[1:]` the iterator has yielded all its values because the invocation of `readlines` calls `__next__` on `f` until there are no lines left.

Now here's the problem: After you have done all that, you issue `for lines in f` i.e. you try to loop over the iterator again. But since it is empty, the body of your `for` loop will never be executed.

There are several ways to fix your code. The most straight forward is to loop over your list `lines`, not `f`, i.e. something like `for line in lines`.

On the other hand, it does not seem like you need a full fledged list of all the lines prior to iteration, so consider just looping over `f` directly without calling `readlines` beforehand.

Comment: but don't forget to skip that first line. You could do `next(f, None)` before the loop to achieve that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I cannot use next, try/except, or import any modules. I can only use  functions: len(), range(), int(), float(), str(), set(), dict(), bool(), tuple()
 file reading: open(), .close(), .read(), .readline(), .readlines(), with syntax
 dictionaries: all methods listed in our slides on that chart
 methods: lists: .insert(), .append(), .extend(), .pop(), .remove()
strings: .strip(), .split(), .join()
 sorted(), .sort(), reversed(), .reverse()

Comment: I am unfamiliar with your method timgeb. How can I iterate over f if it hasn't been opened for reading?

Comment: @ocean.1234 I never said that you should not open `f` for reading. I said don't call `readlines`.

Comment: @ocean.1234: you may be so constrained, but other visitors to this page in the future won't be. I'm teaching *not just you* about Python techniques.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's completely fine, but you can also teach BOTH me and visitors to do it without constraints as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
lines=f.readlines()[1:] #skip first line
d={} #create dictionary
for line in lines: #iterate for all lines
    if ':' in line:            
        x=line.strip().split(':') #split at colon
        a=x[0] #map keys to values
        b=x[1]
        d[a]=b #add to dictionary
return d #return dictionary
    ...
```

Otherwise if no colon in the line, you will get `IndexError`.

Comment: The posted code was not broken. How does this fix the issue? Leaving in the newline won't produce an empty dictionary.

Comment: This actually got the function to execute. Now I just have an out of range error.

Comment: @ocean.1234: are you saying you got errors before, or that the function *didn't run*?

Comment: @stanleyli Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester5p.py", line 305, in test_read_info_file_05
    self.assertEqual(read_info_file(DATAFILE),info_db5())
  File "/Users/kgreenwo/Desktop/student.py", line 8, in read_info_file
    b=x[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't have an error before, I was just getting empty dictionaries for every test case, which meant my function didn't work properly.

Comment: See, this is why you need to **explain in your answer** what you fixed. I had missed the iteration over `f` vs. `lines`, but your answer doesn't enlighten on that point either.

Comment: @ocean.1234 try this time

Comment: @stanleyli That returns an empty dictionary

Comment: @ocean.1234 I don't think any more issue in the code. Are you sure you have colon in each line? Try to print out `x` for each line to verify

Comment: I see where I tripped up. There aren't colons, there are commas. The key may contain one comma, and the value may have as many commas needed.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the number of commas before splitting. How can I do that?

Comment: @ocean.1234 if there is no colon, what do you use to split the text? You don't have to care about the number of commas if you know what delimiter you want to use to split.

Comment: If there is a comma in the The second comma is what I use to split. That's why I need to keep track of the number of commas.  Name field in the input file might contain one comma as part of the string, for example,
"Tornadus, (Incarnate Form)". You can assume the name can have at most one comma and all other fields do not have any comma. Example input: info_file2 = '''"ID","Name","Type 1","Type 2","Generation","Legendary"
169,"Crobat","Poison","Flying",2,"FALSE"
6,"Charizard","Fire","Flying",1,"FALSE"
643,"Reshiram","Dragon","Fire",5,"TRUE"

Comment: @stanleyli so basically the split is right after the id which will be a comma

Comment: You input is apparently a csv file, I would use `csv` library to process (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), and it would be pretty easy. Or `regex`. It's not wise to process a complicated string format manually in Python.

Comment: @stanleyli Unfortunately I have to do it manually. I can't use modules.